# Blockbench geckolib animation is facing the wrong way

Tags: minecraft

I am making a Minecraft mob and finished the animations. I then tested it in the game to realize it is facing backward.

Is there a way to invert animations in block bench gecko-lib?

Answer (score 0):

Select what you want to flip (for the entire model just left click in one corner of the UV map, hold left click and and drag the opening square to the opposite corner), transform -> flip -> choose the coordinate you want to flip it around (X or Z for you) and done.